# Xcode - But... Where are our archives?

Tags: xcode, build, crash, archive, xcarchive

I've submitted three versions of my app onto the App Store using the Build and Archive commands. But... Where are those archives?

I've just learnt that I just need them to be able to read crashlogs.  My `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` folder is empty (in fact there is one xarchive file inside it I've just generated now to test a crashlog reading).

Spotlight does not find any .xarchive.

I never been asked to delete or clear anything else than my project builds (Product - clean) when coding next version.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd4wj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd4wj.png) This is the keyboard shortcut that I use

Comment: I appreciate that you added the location of the Archives folder. I was missing archives, and it was because I accidentally deleted that folder with my DerivedData folder... Upon recovering that folder (thankfully still in the trash), my archives showed correctly in the Window->Organizer->Archives area.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct

Answer (score 703, accepted):

- Open the *Organizer* window in Xcode (menu **Window > Organizer**)
- Click on the *Archives* icon in the top middle
- Select the desired archive by app name and date
- Click *Show in Finder* in the context menu

Comment: That's what I did, nothing but the last one I've generated for test purpose.

Comment: Did you upgrade XCode since you built the missing archives? In particular, was it a major upgrade such as from XCode 3 to 4 or with a prior uninstall of XCode?

Comment: I'm afraid your archives are gone then (for whatever reasons).

Comment: Uhhh, what ? But.... Well, last chance, I see that spotlight don't find the last one I have under the eyes. How may I solve this problem to be able  to check if there are NO xarchive on my mac ?

Comment: Window > Organizer... Yea, because that makes obvious sense Apple.

Comment: where that 'window' thing is

Comment: Well done apple. Another step in the process of making stuff impossible...

Comment: I just did this a week ago and now i'm back here again. why is this ui hard to remember?

Comment: Funny how a company like Apple can make the most well-thought, intuitive, simple interfaces for users, but the biggest piles of unusable shit for developers.

Comment: Could not agree more - xcode in general very special in that sense

Comment: Xcode 14.. you have to right click on the app icon in Archives

Comment: @iuliu.net not true! xcode has 5 stars on the app store and is ranked #1 for developers! :D ...*cough**

Answer (score 52):

## Archive Organizer

- To open it: Xcode menu bar > Window > Organizer > Products > Archives
- **Path:** The archives are stored in `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/$DATE/Project Name Datetime.xcarchive`, it's easier to just right click the archive to show path in the organizer though.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Archive location**

To Archive

```
<select_device_or_any_ios_device> -> Product -> Archive
```

By default location is on the same level as `Derived Data` folder

```
<some_path>/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives
//e.g.
/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-05-08/ServiceLocator 08.05.2021, 15.35.xcarchive
```

To change location

```
xcodebuild archive -archivePath "<some_path>/<some_name>.xcarchive" <...>
//or
Xcode -> Preferences... -> Locations -> Locations -> Archives
```

[image]

To show Organizer

```
Window -> Organizer -> Archives
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this since I'm unable to edit @Codo's answer, but for my version of Xcode (12.3) there was no Archive icon in the top middle. Just a slight difference. Instead, going to **Window > Organizer** opened a window displaying all my Archives for the current project. Right clicking each shows a menu to delete Archive entries or you can `Show in Finder`.

`Show in Finder` shows mine are currently located at `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` and within that directory there's a folder for each date which contains an Archive.

Answer (score 1):

if you choose any ios simulator iphone 7 or iphone 8 or any simulateur you have to change this select to ( Any ios Device ) after that the archive option will display