# How to archive/export Framework in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have a project with a framework target, but when I archive, the framework does not show up in organizer. I checked apple for documentation, but only found [reference for static libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html).

Has anyone experienced this before?

Here are screenshots of my current scheme settings
[image: Build Scheme]
[image: Release Scheme]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go into your framework and build.

`cmd+b`

You will find in your products YOUR_FRAMEWORK.framework

[image]

Right click on "YourLibrary.framework" -> Show in Finder

[image]

Now you can share/import your library.

Attention: Don't link/reference to this path because the framework is stored in [Derived Data](https://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/02/01/xcode-derived-data).

Comment: This build is not through archiving. Something only effective on archiving (e.g ENABLE_BITCODE) will not take effect. How do we handle this?

Comment: Furthermore, this answer will by default produce a debug build created only for the system's current architecture, rather than a universal binary release.

Answer (score 4):

The steps are documented by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle?changes=_9)

> Set up the project
>
> To set up your project for creating an XCFramework, ensure your Xcode project has a scheme that builds only the framework target and its dependencies.
>
> Configure these build settings on your target:
>
> Set the **Build Libraries for Distribution** build setting to **Yes**. For Swift, this enables support for library evolution and generation of a module interface file.
>
> Set the **Skip Install** build setting to **No**. If enabled, the built products aren‘t included in the archives.
>
> Leave the **Architectures** build setting **unset**. The predefined value configures the target to build a universal binary for all the possible architectures the target platform uses.

Then you can use **Archive** to build your framework for Release.

Once built, the **Organizer** window will open.
You can then click on **Distribute Content -> Build Products** and export your framework.

Comment: This ought to be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes the approved answer is convenient , but this is the correct answer right here. Especially if setting up CI/CD , do it right.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should do is build the target,then show Products in finder ,you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

**Archive framework**

```
Product -> Archive
//or
xcodebuild archive
```

[[Archive location]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67447941/4770877)

Xcode v12 does not have such problem and when you try to archive a framework Xcode  prompt you to corresponding Archives window

`Archive` is an action from `Scheme`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877) which is competitor for `Build` action. `Archive` includes `Build` with additional logic. For example `Archive` is used for `XCFramework`[<sup>[Example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67181295/4770877) which additionally can contains `.dSYM` and `.BCSymbolMap` files

For usual purposes you can just use `Build` action, it creates a corresponding `.framework` file in a `Build location`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512068/4770877)