# How to export/get xxx.framework by using Xcode 11.4?

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode11.4

Before Xcode 11.4 I built project and I also could found xxx.framework in the path of  xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos.

After using Xcode 11.4, I can't found any xxx.framework in that path.

I have seen the link, [How to archive/export Framework in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271874/how-to-archive-export-framework-in-xcode) I follow the step to get the framework but Xcode 11.4 doesn't.

Does anybody know how to get the framework by using Xcode 11.4?

Answer (score 2):

Here's two methods.

**Method 1** (The method you say is not working for you but most popular):

- Clean your framework (*Not necessary but good practice*)

  > `Shift + Command + K` or `Product > Clean Build Folder` (Some ask: where is this `Product`. Just hover your mouse at the top of the screen whilst in Xcode, you'll see it there.)
- Build your framework

  > `Command + B` or `Product > Build`
- Export/Extract/Copy your framework

  > On the left panel of Xcode (*Where you see all your folders and swift files*), expand the folder that's named `Products` (*tap on the little white arrow next to the folder `Products` to expand it and see its contents.*)

  > Once you expanded the `Products` folder, you should see a very good looking framework staring right at you. The name should look something like this `YourProjectName.framework`

  > Now to finally answer your question - **HOW TO EXPORT THE FRAMEWORK**...well right click on the framework (the `YourProjectName.framework`) and click on `Show in Finder`.

  > Once you clicked on `Show in Finder`, you'll see your `YourProjectName.framework` folder. Yes yes, it looks like a normal folder. That's because it is. Everyone just makes it sound fancy.

  > And there you go. You can then just drag that fancy-ish `YourProjectName.framework` folder into you project.

**Method 2** (Here I'll assume you already read method 1 so I'll explain with less detail):

- Clean your framework (Not necessary but good practice)
- Archive your framework

  > `Product > Archive` (Don't be surprised if you wait a couple of seconds for it to archive.)

  > Once it's done archiving. You'll see it opens a new Xcode like window. If you don't see this window, it means you were busy with other stuff on your mac at the time it finished. Don't worry haha, just look around on your mac until you find it. If you still don't find it, chances are the archiving failed. If it failed, Xcode will give you an error log. Read it, fix it, try archiving again.

  > Once it finished archiving and you see the Xcode-like window. Your archive will be highlighted. It just shows its selected.
- Export/Extract/Copy your framework

  > Right click on the archive and say `Show in Finder`

  > The finder will open and have your archive selected.

  > Right click on that archive and select `Show Package Contents`

  > The finder will open your archives contents.

  > Navigate to your framework which is located under `Products > Library > Frameworks`

  > There you'll find your `YourProjectName.framework` folder. select that folder and drag it into your project.

If none of the above methods worked for you, I guess it opens the opportunity for you to find another way. When you do, come back to this answer and add your method so we all can learn.